# How to use inline code in markdown in Jupyter with R

Tags: r, markdown, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How to use inline code in markdown in Jupyter with R?

**CODE CELL**

```
n <- 8
```

**MARKDOWN CELL**

```
The Number is {{n}}
```

What would be the correct syntax in Jupyter Markdown for R? Is it even possible?

Comment: Since you use the syntax `{{n}}`, I assume you have the corresponding [Markup extension for Python](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/python-markdown) installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you haven't done it already, you might want to give the [python markdown](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/python-markdown) extension a shot, that adds the markdown inline code functionality for Python to Jupyter notebooks. On their github they claim:

> The Python Markdown extension allows displaying output produced by the current kernel in markdown cells. **The extension is basically** **agnostic to the kernel language**, however most testing has been done using Python.

[Installation instructions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions#installation) are on the github page of the nbextensions. Make sure you'll enable the python markdown extension using a [jupyter command](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions#3-enablingdisabling-extensions) or the [extension configurator](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator).

Calling variables then should work inside a markdown cell with the `{{var-name}}` syntax that you've already given (described in the [readme](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/python-markdown) of the corresponding github page (linked in the [wiki](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/wiki/python-markdown))).

---

If this doesn't help, you might want to join the discussion of the corresponding issues in the issue trackers for [ipython](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1098) and [jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1098).

Comment: thx. I simply forgot to enable it via `jupyter nbextension enable python-markdown/main`